# Updating a string using regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm pretty sure that my question is very straightforward but I cannot find the answer to it. Let's say we have an input string like:

`input = "This is an example"`

Now, I want to simply replace every word --generally speaking, every substring ***using a regular expression***, "word" here is just an example-- in the input with another string ***which includes the original string too***. For instance, I want to add an `@` to the left and right of every word in input. And, the output would be:

```
output = "@This@ @is@ @an@ @example@"
```

What is the solution? I know how to use `re.sub` or `replace`, but I do not know how I can use them in a way that I can update the original matched strings and not completely replace them with something else.

Comment: couldn't you do something like `" ".join(["@"+x+"@" for x in input.split(" ")])`

Comment: @Hippolippo Not sure this works if I want to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capture groups for that.

```py
import re

input = "This is an example"
output = re.sub("(\w+)", "@\\1@", input)
```

A capture group is something that you can later reference, for example in the substitution string. In this case, I'm matching a word, putting it into a capture group and then replacing it with the same word, but with `@` added as a prefix and a suffix.

You can read about regexps in python more in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `re.sub` with lookarounds:

```
input = "This is an example"
output = re.sub(r'(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)', '@', input)

print(output)

@This@ @is@ @an@ @example@
```

Answer (score 0):

This is without re library

```
a = "This is an example"
l=[]
for i in a.split(" "):
    l.append('@'+i+'@')

print(" ".join(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match only word boundaries with `\b`:

```
import re

input = "This is an example"
output = re.sub(r'\b', '@', input)
print(output)


@This@ @is@ @an@ @example@
```